# using wilson's theorem calculate 28!(mod 799)

Tags: number-theory

Using Wilson's theorem calculate

$$28!\pmod {799}$$

I try to apply Wilson's theorem  where if $p$ is prime then $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$

$799 = 17*47$ then we have two equations

$16! =-1\pmod{17}$

$46! =-1\pmod{47}$

for first one

$$28\cdot 27\cdot 26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16!=-1\pmod{17}$$

will equal 
$12\cdot 16!=-1\pmod{17}$

for second 
$$46\cdot 45\cdot 44\cdot 43\cdot 42\cdot 41\cdot 40\cdot39\cdot 38\cdot 37\cdot 36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot 33\cdot 32\cdot 31\cdot 30\cdot 29\cdot 28! =-1\pmod{47}$$

I'm stuck here , can't continue and need help

Comment: Don't you think $28!$ is divisible by $17$, so modulo $17$ it is congruent to ...?

Comment: This is a bizarre question! :)

Answer (score 0):

$46.45.44.43.42...29.28! \equiv -1$ (mod 47)

$28! \equiv \frac{-1}{46.45.44...29}$ (mod 47)

$28! \equiv \frac{-1}{-1.-2.-3...-18} \equiv \frac{1}{-18!}\equiv -\frac{1} {3628800.132.182.240.306}$ (mod 47)

$10!=3628800\equiv338800 \equiv9800\equiv400\equiv24$ (mod 47)

$132\equiv38\equiv-9$ (mod 47)

$182\equiv41\equiv-6$  (mod 47)

$240 \equiv 5$ (mod 47)

$306 \equiv 24$ (mod 47)

So

$28!\equiv-\frac{48}{54.24.120}\equiv -\frac{1}{54.60}\equiv -\frac{48}{54.60}\equiv-\frac{4}{5.54}\equiv-\frac{4}{5.7}\equiv-\frac{4}{35}\equiv \frac{4}{12} \equiv \frac{1}{3} \equiv \frac{48}{3}\equiv16$
(mod 47)

$28!\equiv 0 \equiv 16+47k \equiv-1+13k$ (mod 17)

So $k\equiv\frac{1}{13}\equiv \frac{18}{30}\equiv \frac{3}{5}\equiv \frac{20}{5} \equiv 4$ (mod 17)

Therefore, $28!\equiv16+47.(4+17k')\equiv16+188\equiv204$ (mod 799)

The modulo operations are licit because in all cases, $gcd(modulus,denominator)=1.$